# Adding translation of "potential" to "ad infinitum"

Tags: idiom, translation-check

The phrase "ad infinitum" is often used in texts that are otherwise non-Latin. I would like to use a variation of this phrase in an English text. In philosophy of mathematics there is a distinction, going back to Aristotle, between potential infinity and actual infinity. I would like to make it clear that I'm referring to the former kind. Can I write "ad infinitum potentialis" or something like that (sorry if my guess is completely of the mark - I know next to nothing about Latin).

The full sentence would be as follows: "The claim is that the free creation of sequences - an arbitrary choice of an element, followed by another arbitrary choice of an element, *ad infinitum potentialis* - can result in sequences that cannot be defined."

Comment: [Potential versus Completed Infinity:
its history and controversy](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/thereals/potential.html)

Comment: Frankly, as long as the writing is in English, I'd prefer, for the sake of clarity at the expense of the fancy, “and thus to potential infinity."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest *ad infinitum in potentia*. The phrase *infinitum in potentia* seems to be [quite established](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=kGF&channel=fs&ei=S-xzW9e5IOmOgAaW2JSQCQ&q=%22infinitum+in+potentia%22&oq=%22infinitum+in+potentia%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...61511.63091.0.63600.2.2.0.0.0.0.358.503.0j1j0j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.jWt3CTQksdE) in philosophy and natural sciences, as you can see from the hits in that link. For instance, [this text](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kxtlAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA313&lpg=PA313&dq=infinitum+%22in+potentia%22&source=bl&ots=IHa7XaHvRl&sig=v0Ez_f41ZKVmTUmo9-wQzGw2m6c&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXi87C2e7cAhVpB8AKHRYsBZIQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=infinitum%20%22in%20potentia%22&f=false) discusses the modes of being infinity (Chapter VI is titled *quonam modo sit infinitum*). One paragraph mentions *infinitum in potentia* and *infinitum actu*. So this distinguished between the potential and the actual infinity. A similar distinction between *potentia* and *actu* is found in Aquinas, (e.g. in the phrase *In Deo nihil est in potentia quod non sit in actu*, [here](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/qdp1.html)).

Actually, according to the book "[Guide to Latin in International Law](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780195369380.001.0001/acref-9780195369380-e-970)", *in potentia* seems to be a Latin phrase. That article (in the full access version) states its meaning as:

> In potentiality ... Contrast with *In actu*.

Meanwhile, *[In actu](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780195369380.001.0001/acref-9780195369380-e-886#)* entry defines this expression as "In practice; in action". Both entries have this example, showing the contrast:

> As regards the *pactum de compromittendo*, international law has made certain progress in developing the formulas regulating passage from arbitration *in potentia* to arbitration *in actu*, particularly in respect of the appointment of arbitrators by the act of a third party.

*In potentia* also has the benefit of being an English phrase [meaning potentially](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_potentia).

Comment: "In potentia" and "in actu" are indeed the terms commonly used in Scholastic philosophy.